# Regex group of characters respecting the structure

Tags: .net, regex

I am working on a regular expression that allows me 10 numbers, but if there are more than ten numbers it is necessary to add a | did up to a minimum 1 time or maximum 30 times.

Which has the following structure: `1234567890|`

This is my regular expression

```
^([0-9]{10})+((-([0-9]{10})+)+)$
```

**valid**

- `1234567890|`
- `1234567890|1234567890|`
- `1234567890|1234567890|1234567890|`
- `1234567890|1234567890|1234567890|` ...maximum 30 times

**not valid**

- `123456`
- `1234567890`
- `1234567890|12345`

or more than 30 times

Comment: Match Collection has a parameter indicating number of times match is found.  So you can check if you exceed 30 from the collection instead of in the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that you are using a *hyphen* in your pattern but want to match *vertical bars* your current regex seems too complicated. Looks like you just need to use one [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) for [repitition](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).

```
^(?:\d{10}\|){1,30}$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/12Pj8d/1)

Comment: You saved me, I hardly do regular expressions, as you mention I was doing a very complex one, I knew it was a matter of grouping but I didn't know how to implement it. Thanks for your help.